# Trying to use xRDP and use ports for each user

Tags: server, 13.10, xrdp

It's been a suggestion to use port 5912 if you want a user to connect only to that port so that they can return into their session. I've done this to my root user, DELTA, and it worked shortly until the next reboot to receive this error.

http://puu.sh/7U4Sx.jpg

In my xrdp.ini, this is what you see for the few sessions

```
[xrdp1]
name=Delta
lib=libvnc.so
username=delta
password=ask
ip=127.0.0.1
port=5912

[xrdp2]
name=Beta
lib=libvnc.so
username=beta
password=ask
ip=127.0.0.1
port=5913
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to put this command

```
sudo /etc/init.d/xrdp restart
```

in /etc/rc.local.

```
sudo nano /etc/rc.local
sudo /etc/init.d/xrdp restart &&
```

This command will restart/start servis after boot process is complete and all other services is up.

Comment: Adding that to the rc.local did nothing. Still get the same error after reboot.

Comment: Please try command in console. Maybe a make mistake in path. Idea is to restart service after booting. Try to see `sudo netstat -a` to see xrdp is on listen state for port 5912 & 5913. Also do `ps -ax | grep xrdp` to see process is running. If not look in xrdp.log for reason. xrdp.log is in  ${XRDP_LOG_DIR}/xrdp.log

Comment: NetBIOS reports that those ports aren't being listened. I must note that I still use the normal port for RDP and I'm doing this because I'm told that if you give a port to each user, you could have each user return to their own session instead of creating a new session

Comment: VNC work on port 5900. Do you listen on that port?